# Error with std::bad_alloc() after 3-4 runs of program, not sure why

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

This is code for a war card game. After running it for a number of times (varies each time), it throws a `std::bad_alloc()` error, and I'm not sure why. Card.h and deck.h are fine, but if this code looks good I will post them if needed.

```
#ifndef WAR_H
#define WAR_H
/*
  This runWar function runs a game of war between 2 automated players
  and returns the number of rounds (both put a card down
  once per round) until someone won. An integer is given
  as an upper limit to how many rounds a game can go for.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>

#include "deck.h"

using namespace std;

int runWar(unsigned int limit)
{
    // fill me in!
    Card aCards[52];
    Deck d; // starting deck
    int roundcounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        int numCards = 0;
        // create cards
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i ++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 13; j++)
            {
                Card tC;
                tC.setValues(j,i);
                //d.push(*tC);
                // add to array for shuffling
                aCards[numCards] = tC;
                numCards = numCards + 1;
            }
        }
    }






    // shuffling

    for (int n = 0; n < 52; n++)
    {

        int index = rand() % 51;
        Card holder = aCards[index];
        aCards[index] = aCards[n];
        aCards[n] = holder;
    }

    for (int m = 0; m <= 51; m++)
    {
        d.addCard(aCards[m]);
    }

    // SUCCESSFULLY CREATES 52 CARD DECK

    // DECKS SUCCESSFULLY RANDOM


    // D - starting deck

    // deal out cards to each player

    queue<Card> p1; // player 1 deck
    queue<Card> p2; // player 2 deck

    while (d.size() != 0)
    {
        p1.push(d.getTopCard());
        if (d.size() != 0)
        {
            p2.push(d.getTopCard());
        }
    }

    // SUCCESSFULLY DEALS 26 cards to each player

    bool winner = false;

    // Play game
    while (winner == false)
    {
        Card one = p1.front();
        Card two = p2.front();

        if(!p1.empty())
        {
            p1.pop();
        }
        if(!p2.empty())
        {
            p2.pop();
        }

        if(one.getRank() > two.getRank())
        {
            // player 1 wins
            roundcounter++;
            p1.push(one);
            p1.push(two);
        }
        else if(one.getRank() < two.getRank())
        {
            // player 2 wins
            roundcounter++;
            p2.push(one);
            p2.push(two);
        }
        else
        {
            // WAR
            stack<Card> cardpile;

            bool war_donechecker = false;
            while(war_donechecker == false)
            {
                for( int w=0; w<3; w++)
                {
                    cardpile.push(p1.front());
                    cardpile.push(p2.front());
                    if(!p1.empty())
                    {
                        p1.pop();
                    }
                    if(!p2.empty())
                    {
                        p2.pop();
                    }
                }
                Card p11 = p1.front();
                Card p22 = p2.front();

                cardpile.push(p11);
                cardpile.push(p22);
                if(!p1.empty())
                {
                    p1.pop();
                }
                if(!p2.empty())
                {
                    p2.pop();
                }
                if(p11.getRank() > p22.getRank())
                {
                    roundcounter++;
                    while(!(cardpile.empty()))
                    {
                        p1.push(cardpile.top());
                        cardpile.pop();
                    }
                    p1.push(one);
                    p1.push(two);
                    war_donechecker = true;
                }
                else if(p11.getRank() > p22.getRank())
                {
                    roundcounter++;
                    while(!(cardpile.empty()))
                    {
                        p2.push(cardpile.top());
                        cardpile.pop();
                    }
                    p2.push(one);
                    p2.push(two);
                    war_donechecker = true;
                }
            }
            if (p1.empty() || p2.empty())
            {
                winner = true;
            }
        }
        cout << roundcounter << endl;
    }
    return roundcounter;
}

#endif
```

Comment: You can use a debugger to find out where the error occurs.

Comment: Off topic: this looks like an implementation file, not a header. You should not need the header guards.

Comment: Please post more information or a stack trace of the error.

Comment: What is the definition of the objects? Are there any dynamic allocations done in them? Next thing to check -- make sure that your vectors/queues/maps are being erased in entirety prior to re-adding objects.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add some description and represent the necessary part of the code so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!